# Avoiding double tracking if parent and iframe runs the same Google Analytics

Tags: iframe, google-analytics

I want to block GA tracking from iframe within my website, which is a parent, GA is set in the script on the product site, there is a description of the product which is an iframe.

At the moment it double the pageview number. Is it possible to block iframe tracking, so it will only tack the product page (parent one).

Greetings

Comment: Is the domain of the iFrame the same as the domain of the page that iFrame appears?  If not, a pageview should not be getting counted twice UNLESS you've set up cross domain tracking AND initialized the same GA property on the page that lives in the iFrame.

Comment: It is on the same domain, thx for the respond. Any ideas what should i do?

Comment: Since the page in the iFrame is the same domain as the page holding the iFrame, you technically have two page views.  However, each pageview should be reporting its respective page in GA meaning that you should have one pageview for the page holding the iFrame and one pageview for the page inside of the iFrame.  Is there a reason that you don't want to count the pageview for the iFrame page?  If so, you could remove the GA tracking code completely from the iFrame page.   Do you have a link to your site that you could provide to give me a better idea of what we're working with?